# How to retrieve additional info from a logged in user without accessing DB every time

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Identity Framework. My application has several subscriptions. Today, subscription Id is stored on the `ApplicationUser` Object and persisted to database context.

Every web call I'm looking at the database in order to get the `subscriptionId` property of the logged in user.

How can I avoid this database call for the logged in user?

Comment: So, you don't try to implement REST API using ASP.NET Core, right?

Comment: You can use a "claim" for this: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Kirk said in the comments you can use claims for this.

You need to add `subscriptionId` to `ClaimsIdentity` when user is logging-in and retrieve the value in your controller.

I assume you have a `subscriptionId` property in `ApplicationUser`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
}
```

For adding custom claims you need to implement `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);

        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("subscription_id", user.SubscriptionId));

        return claimsIdentity;
    }
}
```

`user.SubscriptionId` must be a string. in other case you can create a property to cast the value to an string.

`public string SubscriptionIdStting => SubscriptionId.ToString();`

Register it to `IServiceCollection`

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

You can access `SubscriptionId` in Controller or Page like this :

```
User.FindFirst("subscription_id").Value
```